# Mapping .Net decimal with large number of fraction to SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server

If I have a decimal like 32.593170731707329023999999999 - what SQL Datatype, and precision and scale should I use?

My integer parts are pretty small (1-10000) and fraction part big.

Have tried decimal with different variations of precision and scale, but get an overflow exception in .Net.

Comment: What .net datatype are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
DECLARE @D DECIMAL(38, 33)

SELECT @D = 10000.593170731707329023999999999 

SELECT @D
```